# Getting error when connecting mssql server from laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, laravel, laravel-5

When I am trying to connect mssql server from localhost,using laravel 5.2 framework, I am getting following error.

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
```

My PHP.Ini settings is,

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

PHP version is,

```
PHP Version 5.6.11
```

I included those modules,
[image]

If I enabled,

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

I am getting error that failed to load `mssql.dll` and it seems to missing there ext folder.

I am got stuck here and help to find solution.

Comment: Just because you have the extension doesn't necessarily mean you've got the driver installed. You need both.

Comment: sorry...i couldn't understand you

Comment: Also make sure you restart your web server after changes to php.ini or installing drivers

Comment: Yes.. I restarted and it is loading both `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` modules.

Comment: Download and install the ms driver from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

Comment: Yes... from there only I downloaded and installed php_pdo_sqlsrv_56.dll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113735/discussion-between-muhammed-shihab-and-jeff-puckett-ii).